# RAD Studio Seattle Menu Confused

Tags: delphi, menu, delphi-10-seattle

I installed FastMM to trace memory leaks in an application.  Not blaming FastMM just mentioning.  After resolving the problems with my application, I noticed that the File->Open & File->Exit menu behaviours have been reversed.

I select File->Open, RAD studio closes.  I select File->Exit, RAD studio opens a file dialog.

The icon bar icons work as they should.  Does anyone know a fix?

Comment: @J Looks like Seattle..

Comment: based on : the title of the question includes the RAD studio version :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the following article on Embarcadero's support site:

[Action event handlers for the File|Open and File|Exit menu handlers are swapped in RAD Studio/Delphi/C++ Builder](http://support.embarcadero.com/article/44075)

> Abstract: Action event handlers for the File|Open and File|Exit menu
>   handlers are swapped when **unsigned DLLs reside in the “bin” folder of
>   RAD Studio**
>
> Some customers have reported this strange behavior in the product in
>   the past. It seems always related to have unsigned DLLs in the “bin”
>   folder of the product (for instance, C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\bin in an XE6 default installation).
>
> **Only files provided by Embarcadero may reside in the bin folder**.
>   Common files which are mistakenly copied to the bin folder are third
>   party components and database drivers (for example sqlite3.dll or
>   libmysql.dll). The easiest way to determine if this might be your
>   problem is to list files by timestamp and look for files created
>   before or after the release of your product.

Comment: This was the answer.  Moved the FastMM .dll's into a separate folder, and the IDE works as expected.  So I guess I will have to add a search path, or just copy the dll's when I need to test.  Oddly enough, I do have an sqlite dll with no ill effect.